# Prevent errors display while still adding the error classes from the js (not with the attribute)

Tags: parsley.js

Is there a way to prevent errors display while still adding the error classes from the js (not with the attribute)? If I use `uiEnabled: true` I get neither.
[This issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/214) solves the problem with attributes, but not from js code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply hide the error messages with CSS?

Indeed, that's exactly what CSS is for.

`Parsley` generates error messages and classes, it's then up to you to provide the CSS for the display to match the look what you want. If that's `display:none` on the error messages, that's fine.

Realize that when designing a library like `Parsley`, the priority is to add features for things are difficult to achieve without it and fairly common. Hiding messages is neither difficult (it's one line of CSS) nor common, so it shouldn't be surprising that there isn't an option for it.

Comment: I do not like doing this kind of things. This seems like a hacky thing to do. I am sure there must be a way to do it right.

Comment: This absolutely does provide an answer to the question. Parsley provides error messages, it's up to the developper to decide where and how they are displayed (if at all, e.g. `display: none`). The best and easiest way to do this is via CSS.
I won't add a useless feature to the library because someone thinks a perfectly valid way to do things is too "hacky" and not right.

Comment: Answering a question with a question can be very confusing. In the Q&A format surely and answer should  be clearly that..... otherwise it looks like a comment. (Hence the reponse the LQP review Queue)

Comment: I find it very odd that moderators believe that my answer was objectively worse than no answer at all. Answer edited, hopefully this one won't be deleted?